# A lot of InvocationTargetException after starting tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, cxf, java-11

When I start tomcat with my apps I see a lot of:

```
02-Aug-2021 16:49:24.011 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Failed to scan [file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/lib/jakarta.annotation-api.jar] from classloader >
        java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206)
                ... 51 more
        Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/lib/jakarta.annotation-api.jar
                at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)

WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/lib/woodstox-core.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/lib/woodstox-core.jar
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
```

and many, many more. In `/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/lib` I have jars but instead of `jakarta.annotation-api.jar` there is `-rwxr-x--- 1 root   root    25K sie  2 16:49 jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar`. I think that's the problem - it's looking for jars without versions, but I have no idea why. How to force tomcat to take proper jars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `*.loader` properties in `catalina.properties` to see if you didn't hardcode those URLs. By default only the `common.loader` property is set to a non-empty value:

```
common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"
```

Another source for these messages might be the manifest scanning feature (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/0f8a19d16d7bb327b54195df6511291b294579fd/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/scan/StandardJarScanner.java#L431)), which also scans JAR files in the same folder mentioned in another JAR file's manifest. To check if this is the case run:

```sh
for jar in /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/lib/*.jar; do
    unzip -p "$jar" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep '^Class-Path';
done
```

To solve the problem you can disable manifest scanning completely, by adding to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`:

```xml
<Context>
  ...
  <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

(cf. [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html))

**Remark**: Unless you are running Tomcat as `root`, your permissions prevent any other user from reading those JAR files. You should at least add read (`r`) permission to the user running Tomcat.

Comment: I have exactly the same `common.loader` as you pasted.

Comment: @Michu93: another possibility is that the JAR files you have in the `lib` folder mention those non-existent JARs in their manifest. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: It's something related to `tomcat/lib` problem - I just noticed that when I did: `rm jaxws-rt-2.3.4.jar` in `tomcat/lib` then error in `catalina.out` disappeared or more like changed - now I can see that `jakarta` jar is no longer in logs but now `WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.50/lib/hk2.jar] from classloader hierarchy` so it must be something related to libraries which I am using ;/

Comment: The `jaxws-rt` artifact has in its manifest: `Class-Path: jakarta.annotation-api.jar jakarta.activation.jar jakarta.mail.jar jakarta.jws-api.jar jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar jakarta.xml.ws-api.jar jakarta.xml.soap-api.jar FastInfoset.jar gmbal-api-only.jar ha-api.jar jaxb-impl.jar management-api.jar mimepull.jar policy.jar saaj-impl.jar stax-ex.jar stax2-api.jar streambuffer.jar woodstox-core.jar`, hence all those warnings. Disable manifest scanning as in the modified answer or rename the JAR files.

Comment: another solution would be `exclude`  from `pom.xml` all those `jakarta.*` from `jaxws-rt`

Comment: No, you need to modify the `Class-Path:` line in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file of the `jaxws-rt-2.3.4.jar` archive. BTW: If you want so many additional APIs in the server's classloader, consider using TomEE instead.

Comment: but it really works also with excluding `jakarta.activation`, `jakarta.xml.bind-api`, `woodstox-core` from `jaxws-rt`. Both ways (excluding and `<JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>`) seems to work similar.